# How to create an endpoint in Sequelize.js that receives any random JSON in the model?

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have created a simple endpoint on an Express server using Sequelize and Postgresql. This endpoint should receive a simple POST request with a JSON Object registering Events as a callback. The thing is, this will be a JSON object with lots of strings and numbers that I can't write a specific model for.

I have two problems with my current model.

I can only receive events that are directed to Event.event when in fact I want to receive whatever JSON that should not start with a key "event" like I wrote on my model. However, I don't actually know how to create a model that allows us to send any unspecified JSON to my table Events.

If I receive those callbacks trying to POST JSONs to this endpoint they are naturally coming as NULL, since they do not fit with Event.event

Here's the model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../db');

const Event = sequelize.define(
    'Event',
    {
        event: {type: Sequelize.JSON, allowNull: false}
    }
);

module.exports = Event;
```

And the router:

```
const { Router } = require("express");
const Event = require("./model");
const router = new Router();

router.get("/event-receiver", (req, res, next) => {
  const limit = req.query.limit || 25;
  const offset = req.query.offset || 0;

  Event.findAll({ limit, offset })
    .then(allEvents => res.json(allEvents))
    .catch(next);
});

router.post("/event-receiver", (req, res, next) => {
  Event.create(req.body)
    .then(newEvent => res.status(201).json(newEvent))
    .catch(next);
});

module.exports = router;
```

My actual question is how could I write a model that takes any type of unspecified JSON that is sent to that endpoint?

For example:

```
{
AnyRandomJSON: {type: Sequelize.JSON, allowNull: False}
}
```

Without actually having to give it a name like "event", but simply receiving anything that is sent to "/event-receiver" and registering on a specific column on my postgresql called Events or Data, anything like that.

By reading the documentation and other related help articles don't enlighten me on how to do that in a simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to fix it by adding a Data to `Event.create()`. Easier than what I thought.

```
router.post("/signrequest-event-receiver", (req, res, next) => {
  Event.create({
    Data: req.body
  })
    .then(console.log(req.body))
    .then((newEvent) => res.status(201).json(newEvent))
    .catch(next);
});
```

With my Model using JASONB

```
const Event = sequelize.define(
    'Events',
    {
        Data: 
        {
            type: Sequelize.JSONB,
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks @RobertoCaboni

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when storing JSON data for restaurants from Yelp. While the data is JSON, its structure was irrelevant.

To avoid incompatibilities (some SQL engines don't support JSON), I ended up storing it as `Sequelize.TEXT`:

```js
    restaurant_yelp_info: Sequelize.TEXT()
```

What you name the column is not that important.

I use `JSON.stringify()` to convert to JSON before storing, if necessary.

I use `JOSN.parse()` to convert the JSON to an object after retrieval.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I couldn't get back to this project yet. But initially my first trial didn't work replacing it to Text. I might need to stringfy indeed.

Comment: The problem seems to be with how Sequelize validates the json object coming. So if my column is called 'event' it tries to match with an object .event, since it's a JSON callback coming from other server. It just gives this validation message error:

"SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: Event.event cannot be null"

Still stuck with this project...